# Calling a method of the tested Activity from a test using espresso and see its results

Tags: android, testing, mockito, android-espresso, dagger-2

I'm creating and Android Application. I'm using Espresso for testing.

I've an Activity with the method:

```
public void render(Recipe recipe){
    //draw the recipe to the activity
}
```

I want to test that this method works correctly.

**Not working solution 1**

I've tested the following

```
@Test
public void viewPaintsRecipes() {
    final Activity activity = activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
    ((MainActivity)activity).render(Arrays.asList(new Recipe[]{recipe}));
    onView(withId(R.id.text)).check(matches(withText(recipe.toString())));
}
```

I get an Exception.

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

**Not working solution 2**

I've also tried to put the two lines inside a runnable runned by a Handler in the main thread, but the test hangs.

How can I acchieve this?

**Notes**

I attach the full test. Note that I use dagger and Mockito too.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class MainActivityTestWithMockPresenter {
    Recipe recipe = new Recipe("sampleTitle");
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MainActivity.class, true, false);

    @Mock
    MainActivityPresenter mockPresenter;
    @Mock
    AndroidApplication mockContext;

    @Before
    public void insertMockedComponent(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        AndroidApplication app = (AndroidApplication) instrumentation.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();
        MyModule mockedMyModule = new MyModule(mockContext){
            @Provides
            public MainActivityPresenter getMainActivityPresenter(){
                return mockPresenter;
            }
        };
        MyComponent component = DaggerMyComponent.builder().myModule(mockedMyModule).build();
        app.setComponent(component);
    }

    @Test
    public void viewPaintsRecipes() {
        final Activity activity = activityRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
        ((MainActivity)activity).render(Arrays.asList(new Recipe[]{recipe}));
        onView(withId(R.id.text)).check(matches(withText(recipe.toString())));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: delete @mock annotations and tell how it would work then

Comment: your mixing unit tests with automated tests

Comment: @piotrek1543 I want to use the mocks, because I want to test only the Activity, not all the layers (Presenter, use cases, etc). if this is not the way, how can I test Activity methods in an issolated way?

Comment: delete mocks and run tests - are they running correctly? Nowadays we need to fix problem - then we would work on change to concept before, ok?

Comment: have done what I said? I really want to help you, but first I need to know what is a reason of issue.

Comment: The problem does not come from the mocks.
The problem is that I want to call a method of the activity inside a test and check its results. This method needs to be called in the main thread but if I try to do it in the main thread, the test hangs.

Answer (score 9):

This answer previously demonstrated how to call a method on the `Activity` under test by means of the `ActivityTestRule.runOnUiThread(Runnable)` method as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    @get:Rule var activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun recipe_is_rendered() {
        // When.
        activityTestRule.runOnUiThread { activityTestRule.activity.render(someRecipe) }

        // Then.
        // assert stuff about the recipe rendering here
    }
}
```

The [ActivityTestRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule) class has since been deprecated and replaced by the [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule) class. The new, preferred way to call a method on the `Activity` under test is by means of the `ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityAction)` method as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    @get:Rule var activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun recipe_is_rendered() {
        // When.
        activityScenarioRule.scenario.onActivity { it.render(someRecipe) }

        // Then.
        // assert stuff about the recipe rendering here
    }
}
```

The only two dependencies I needed to add to my `build.gradle` file to do this were the following:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
```

Comment: We probably don't need `runOnUiThread` with the new AndroidX Test framework.

Comment: Thanks for calling this out Igor. I've updated my answer to call out that the `ActivityTestRule` class is deprecated and the `ActivityScenarioRule` class is now the preferred class to use.